C++ memory order on Apple M1 chip not work: reordering happens even with seq_cst in a StoreStore / LoadLoad litmus test?
With the seq_cst memory order, the following code should never have v1 == 0 and v2 == 2 . But it still just prints Reorder happened on my Apple M1 chip. I really don't know why.
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<int> v1, v2;
sem_t start_1, start_2, complete;

int main() {
    sem_init(&start_1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&start_2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&complete, 0, 0);

    std::thread t1([&] {
        while (true) {
            sem_wait(&start_1);

            v1.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            asm volatile("":: : "memory");
            v2.store(2, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

            sem_post(&complete);
        }
    });

    std::thread t2([&] {
        while (true) {
            sem_wait(&start_2);

            int val1 = v1.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            asm volatile("":: : "memory");
            int val2 = v2.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);

            if (val1 == 0 && val2 == 2) {
                puts("Reorder happened");
            }

            sem_post(&complete);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        v1 = v2 = 0;
        sem_post(&start_1);
        sem_post(&start_2);

        sem_wait(&complete);
        sem_wait(&complete);
    }

    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
    return 0;
}


Update:
Thanks a lot to the Peter Cordes's answer, I missed one of the interleaving possibility. But I'm still confused by the following code. Still, with seq_cst order, I think r1 == 0 and r2 == 0 shouldn't happen. It works well on my x86 Intel machine, but not on my Apple M1 chip.
#include <thread>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> v1, v2;
std::atomic<int> r1, r2;
sem_t start_1, start_2, complete;

int main() {
    sem_init(&start_1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&start_2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&complete, 0, 0);

    std::thread t1([&] {
        while (true) {
            sem_wait(&start_1);

            v1.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            asm volatile("":: :"memory");
            int val = v2.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            asm volatile("":: :"memory");
            r1.store(val, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

            sem_post(&complete);
        }
    });

    std::thread t2([&] {
        while (true) {
            sem_wait(&start_2);

            v2.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            asm volatile("":: :"memory");
            int val = v1.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            asm volatile("":: :"memory");
            r2.store(val, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

            sem_post(&complete);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        v1 = v2 = 0;
        sem_post(&start_1);
        sem_post(&start_2);

        sem_wait(&complete);
        sem_wait(&complete);

        if (r1 == 0 && r2 == 0) {
            printf("reorder detected @ %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
    return 0;
}


sem_wait(&start_2) can exit earlier than sem_wait(&start_1). Non working memory order is a false assumption.

Those values are explainable with seq_cst's interleaving of program-order between threads.
  v1.load gets 0
                     both stores in order
  v2.load gets 2

A correct litmus test for StoreStore or LoadLoad would need to load in the opposite order from stores and see 0 in the second load result, non-zero in the first.
In general, always try to make sure you've ruled out simple interleaving explanations when constructing a reordering litmus test.  Think about what would happen if you stopped in a debugger and single-stepped one thread arbitrarily far while others were stopped.  Or any combination of progress vs. stall between threads.

You probably won't see such reordering in practice even with relaxed from just switching the load order.  Both variables probably end up in the same cache line, so the CPU would have no reason to reorder them.  Especially since both load addresses are ready at the same time.  See C++ atomic variable memory order problem can not reproduce LoadStore reordering example for some suggestions for real-world demos of memory-reordering effects allowed by C++ and the ISA you're targeting.
Related not-quite-duplicate: Can't get c++'s seq_cst memory model to work - another case of a poorly-constructed litmus test where the supposedly-interesting result can happen with seq_cst.  That was for IRIW reordering.

BTW, asm volatile("":: : "memory"); isn't necessary; seq_cst already forbids compile-time reordering of seq_cst operations with each other.  I assume you just put it in to try to make sure when you found a surprising result.

I'm only answering the original question only (the first half of the current question).  See Nate's answer re: the second half, which should really be posted separately.  It looks like a correctly-designed litmus test for a different effect (StoreLoad reordering, which can happen even on x86 with orders weaker than seq_cst), and the answer / explanation for it is unrelated.
One interesting difference between AArch64 and x86 is that AArch64 seq_cst stores are about as weak as ISO C++ allows, the same machine instruction as for release stores, stlr, and can reorder with later ops other than release stores and seq_cst loads/RMWs.
StoreLoad ordering wrt. later seq_cst loads is done by ldar having a special interaction with earlier stlr, waiting for them before taking a value from cache.  But it can reorder with earlier plain stores and plain loads.
Unlike on many ISAs including x86 where the only option that's strong enough is a full barrier somewhere, preventing all StoreLoad reordering.  Since cheap loads are more important than cheap stores, the usual design is to have stores pay the price.  Which makes them slow even if there are no seq_cst loads any time soon (or at all) in the same thread.  e.g. x86 normally uses xchg mem, reg for seq_cst stores, which has an implicit lock prefix.
But as Nate explains, there's nothing subtle about why your litmus test fails on AArch64 macOS.

Thanks a lot to your answer, I did miss one of the interleaving possibilities. But I'm still confused with the other example updated later in the question. Hope you can help me out here.

@Ryaaan: That seems like a very different question; I don't see an obvious explanation after looking for a few minutes.  Should probably get posted separately.  I might want to link this Q&A as a duplicate of some future one with the same mistake, and don't want to clutter up the answer with what's probably going to be a more complicated answer.

@Ryaaan:  I wonder if the semaphore works the way we expect?  Perhaps add sequence numbers to the test: with main loop plus threads supposedly running in lockstep so they know what sequence number to expect from the other thread? So we can detect if they're not.

@Ryaaan: Just to be clear, I mean local non-atomic unsigned counters, and you store those instead of 0, 1, or 2.  Each thread starts its sequence numbers at 0, 1, or 2, and they increment by 4 so the low 2 bits match what's going on here, the high bits are distinct from the previous iteration but match each other.  So there's no chance of an ABA ambiguity or any mixup of where a value came from in relation to other values seen nearby.

Thank you so so so much. I did what you suggest, and found out that the problem actually comes from the spurious implementation of semaphore on OS X as you said above. God knows how much time I spent on it to figure out why.

@Ryaaan: That sounds interesting and worth an answer.  You should post that as a new question with a self-answer, if you have time to write it up.  This usage of semaphores should still create a happens-before relationship from the sem_post to the sem_wait ops, unless the counting is off somehow and one of the non-main threads can do multiple iterations?

@Ryaaan: Anyway, AArch64 seq_cst stores are the same instruction as release; they get seq_cst from ldar not being able to reoder with earlier stlr.  Unlike x86 where seq_cst store includes a full barrier draining the store buffer.  So AArch64 seq_cst stores can reorder with later acquire or weaker ops; x86 stores can't.  But I expected sem_post to be a release operation, not just acquire (and maybe not including acquire at all)

@PeterCordes: Looks like the issue is that POSIX unnamed semaphores in MacOS simply don't work at all; the system calls all fail, but OP's program didn't check for this.

@NateEldredge: Wow, yeah, totally separate question, then.  Should be posted separately with [macos] in the tags, and mentioning semaphores in the title, so people can find it.

MacOS doesn't implement POSIX unnamed semaphores.  When compiling with the system-installed clang++, I get a deprecation warning on sem_init (though "deprecated" is probably not a strong enough word when they mean "non-functional").  Additionally, all the calls to sem_* functions fail.  Always check system call return values, even in trivial test programs.  So your threads are not synchronizing as you think they are.
I changed your second program to use named semaphores instead (sem_open) and it works as expected without any "reorder" messages.  Note that, although I could not find this clearly documented anywhere, it appears that each thread has to call sem_open separately; you can't share the returned sem_t * between threads.
It would be much simpler to use C++20 std::counting_semaphore.
